# C# Is it threadsafe to set dictionary object from one thread, get from other thread

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, volatile

Suppose we have some **strange** class which contains

- public property `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Map {get; private set;}`
- method `Update` which re-sets `Map` dictionary when called.

Is it threadsafe to call method `Update` from one thread and get `Map` from other thread?

```
public class Example
{
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Map{ get; private set; }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items)
    {
        Map = items
            .ToLookup(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First())
            .ToReadOnlyDictionary(); // helper method
    }
}
```

Is it possible that there will be the moment when we call Map getter and it returns null or something in bad state, because of setter execution is not atomic?

Comment: Depends on what you do with the `Example` instance, do you `lock` it while you use the `Map` and `Set`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter no

Comment: Why you thought at all that it would be thread safe then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the `Map` is immutable (can't add, remove, modify elements). I don't actually sure if resetting object not threadsafe. Is it possible that there will be the moment when we call `Map` getter and it returns `null` or something bad, because of setter execution is not atomic

Comment: It depends on your definition of thread safe and how you use that class.

Comment: @Dirk Is it possible that there will be the moment when we call Map getter and it returns null or something bad, because of setter execution is not atomic

Comment: `Map` is a reference type, and assignment to a reference is atomic - so that part of it is threadsafe. However, if another thread is modifying `items` while `Update()` is in-flight, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @sleepy Reference assignment is guaranteed to be atomic. `Map` will return either the old value or the new value returned by `ToReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ok, thanks

Comment: The only issue you will have is if code that uses this relies in getting the same `Map` each time it accesses the property. It might, for example, use `ContainsKey` and then `[]` to lookup the key. That isn't a thread-safety issue, technically - but it may throw exceptions (since the first `Map` may have a certain key but the second `Map` may not).

Comment: Also, using `ToLookup` _then_ `ToDictionary` is odd - what is that code trying to achieve?

Comment: Btw, your code doesn't compile because of this: `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First())`. You're going to create a `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>` but `First()` returns a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`. Maybe you want to use `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().Value)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter oops. Actually the real code is different, I tried to simplify that when wrote this answer and did not check if it compiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Thread safe" is a vague term. Wikipedia defines thread-safe code as:

> Thread-safe code only manipulates shared data structures in a manner
>   that ensures that all threads behave properly and fulfill their design
>   specifications without unintended interaction

So we cannot say that certain piece of code is "thread safe" without knowing that design specification, which includes how this code is actually used.

This code is "thread-safe" in a sense that it's not possible for any thread to observe `Example` object in a corrupted or partial state.

Reference assignment is atomic, so thread that reads `Map` can only read either one vesrion of it or another, it cannot observe partial or intermediate state of `Map`. Because both keys and values of `Map` are immutable (strings) - the whole object is immutable and can safely be used by multiple threads after it was read from `Map` property.

However, doing something like this:

```
var example = GetExample();
if (example.Map.ContainsKey("key")) {
    var key = example.Map["key"];
}
```

Is of course not thread safe, because `Map` object, as a whole, might have changed between check and read from dictionary, in a way that old version contained "key" key, but new version does not. Doing this on the other hand:

```
var example = GetExample();
var map = example.Map;
if (map.ContainsKey("key")) {
    var key = map["key"];
}
```

is fine. Any code that does not rely on `example.Map` to stay the same between reads should be "safe".

So you have to ensure that given code is "thread safe" in your particular use case.

Note that using `ConcurrentDictionary` is absolutely useless here. Since your dictionary is readonly - it's already safe to read it from multiple threads.

Update: valid point raised in a comment is that `ReadOnlyDictionary` by itself does not guarantee that underlying data is not modified, because `ReadOnlyDictionary` is just a wrapper around regular mutable `Dictionary`.

However, in this case you create `ReadOnlyDictionary` in `Update` method from non-shared instance of dictionary (received from `ToDictionary`), which is not used for anything else except wrapping it in `ReadOnlyDictionary`. This is a safe usage, because there is no code which has access to mutable underlying dictionary except `ReadOnlyDictionary` itself, and read only dictionary prevents its modification. Reading from even regular `Dictionary` is thread safe as long as there are no writes.

Comment: _"Note that using ConcurrentDictionary is absolutely useless here. Since your dictionary is readonly - it's already safe to read it from multiple threads"_ But `ReadOnlyDictionary` is just a wrapper around the original dictionary which isn't thread-safe, hence `Example` isn't thread-safe at all because `Map` is `public`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't agree. `ReadOnlyDictionary` in this code is not created from some instance of shared mutable dictionary. It's created with `ToDictionary().ToReadOnlyDictionary()` call, from non-shared, throw-away instance of dictionary. So mutable version is stored only inside `ReadOnlyDictionary`, which prevents its mutation.

Comment: Overloooked that, true

Answer (score 0):

> because of setter execution is not atomic

The safety of this code is not about atomicity (read/write a reference is an atomic operation in .NET, unless you screw up alignment). 
So, the only issue in this code is memory reordering. It might happen that another thread will get the reference to partially constructed object. 
But it may happen only on hardware with weak memory model ('weak' means that a lot of reorderings are allowed and there is not many restrictions). 
To prevent this you just have to publish this reference via `Volatile.Write`, which is `nop` for x86 and x86_64 architectures and a kind of memory fence for ARM and other.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code simpler and less bug-prone you could use *ImmutableDictionary*:

```
public class Example
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Map{ get; private set; } = 
        ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, string>();

    public void Update(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items)
    {
        Map = items
            .ToImmutableDictionary();
    }
}
```

*ImmutableDictionary* is guaranteed to be thread safe so there is no way of breaking it. Usual *Dictionary* is not thread safe however in your implementation there should not be any thread safety issues but this requires this special usage.

*ImmutableDictionary* can be downloaded here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/

Another thread-safe dictionary is *ConcurrentDictionary*. Using it may not necessarily provide additional cost because read operation are lock-free. The docs states:

> Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner.

So those two dictionaries are thread-safe in any case (on dictionary API level) and *Dictionary* is thread-safe in some implementations like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent Collections = Thread Safe :)

I think you should use Concurrent collection. Concurrent Generics make sense for me.